# Cancel http request with Angular 4

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

How can I actually cancel request after `subscribe()` in Angular app???

As usual, I use `unsubscribe()` or `takeUntil()` for cancelling my requests [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugNU1.png).

But I have no idea why it's not working in this case:

```
userSubscription$: Subscription;

loadUser(userId: number) {
  // Cancel request
  if(this.userSubscription$) { this.userSubscription$.unsubscribe(); }

  // Load user
  this.userSubscription$ = this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe((user: User) => {
     // ...
  });
}
```

And getUser in Service with Http:

```
getUser() {
  const url = '...';
  return this.http.get(url)
}
```

I tried with normal solutions but it only cancels `Observable` (means it didn't do anything after loading but requests are still loading => Make my site is slowly).

Any idea why this happens?

> For more information, I'm using:
>
> - Angular 4.0.0
> - Using HttpModule for sending request (not HttpClientModule)

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: What's the code in `getUser`?

Comment: @DavidWalschots, I updated my question above. It's just a simple way for sending request as usual.

Comment: I made a small application myself and that cancels the HTTP requests properly. Of course, if the request finishes before you cancel it, the request won't be cancelled. Might it be that `loadUser` is called extremely quickly, or the request finishes very quickly because it's on localhost? What happens if you set your browser's network speed slower through the developer tools?

Comment: I got your idea. But I cancelled before request is finished (because request is very slow).

Answer (score 0):

Once an HTTP request has returned you the response and you want to unsubscribe the best idea is to use the take operator, try this:

```
this.userService.getUser(userId).take(1) subscribe((user: User) => {
     // ...
  });
```

Import the take operator from rxjs depending on your angular version.

Comment: I want to clear old request before I send new request. Not wait for HTTP request has returned.